# How to calculate BaseAddress in AddHttpClient asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to setup BaseAddress for HttpClient via async call to other service. Like that:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>(async (provider, httpClient) =>
    {
        var otherClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IOtherClient>();
        
        httpClient.BaseAddress = await otherClient.GetBaseAddress();
    });
```

Having this setup each request from httpClient produces the following error:

**'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient**

BUT, when I make it synchronious it all starts to work:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>((provider, httpClient) =>
    {
        var otherClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IOtherClient>();
        
        // remove await on blocking result
        httpClient.BaseAddress = otherClient.GetBaseAddress().Result;
    });
```

Comment: Is this URL something you expect that changes on every call?

Comment: I don't believe `BaseAddress` can be determined asynchronously like that. If you have an asynchronously-determined base address, then the best solution is to pass the full address and never set `BaseAddress` at all. Alternatively, if you *need* `BaseAddress` (e.g., using Refit), you would have to create your own http client factory type.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, No, the URL gets fetched once (from service discovery) and then never changed.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can try using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#named-clients), just pass the path and it will be called, since the base address configured for the client is taken.

Comment: Which .net version are you using?

Comment: If you use service discovery e.g consul, you don't have to do this manually. You can access through service discovery.

Comment: @PeterCsala .net version is 7.0

Comment: @Moshi, yes, that's what I ended up with for now - passing serviceDiscoveryClient to every place where I need httpClient. The problem with that approach is that I had to update a lot of my codebase.

Comment: @IvanStudenikin I can suggest a bit cleaner way, you can load configuration first and later you can use this configuration from dependecy container. 
`services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>().ConfigureHttpClient((serviceProvider, client) =>
            {
                var config = serviceProvider.GetService<IApiConfiguration>();//this is the configuration loaded from serviceDiscovery

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.MyHttpClientBaseAddress);
            });`

Comment: @Moshi, unfortunately I don't have config for service discovery, it works like that: _serviceDiscoveryClient.GetUrlByServiceNameAsync("myservice_name") // will return BaseAddress

Comment: @IvanStudenikin If I may ask, If you have full fledged service discovery, why don't you use SD to call your service rather than manually calling. For example,  suppose you have consul, you can call consul to call your service with service name `myservice_name`. 
`_consulHttpClient.GetAsync<MyServiceResponseObject>("myservice_name", $"/someUri");`

Comment: @Moshi, looks good. Will it be possible to use _consulHttpClient as regular httpClient? For example, I'd like to inject _consulHttpClient  using services.AddHttpClient()

Answer (score 1):

The `AddHttpClient` [does not have any overload](https://AddHttpClient) which anticipates an async method (`Func<..., Task>` or `Func<..., Task<TResult>>`).

So, even though you can write `async (...) => { await ...}` it is not supported. `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` should be used instead of `.Result`

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>((_, httpClient) =>
{
   var otherClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IOtherClient>();
   var baseAddress = otherClient.GetBaseAddress().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);  
});
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

With the [`HostInitActions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HostInitActions) nuget package, you can do the following:

1. Create a helper class to perform the async call and register the component

```
public class DynamicClientRegister 
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(IServiceCollection collection)
    {
        var basUrl = await ...;
        collection.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>( httpClient => httpClient.BaseAddress = baseUrl);
    }
}
```

2. Register the helper class via the nuget package provided extension methods

```
builder.Services.AddAsyncServiceInitialization()
    .AddInitAction<DynamicClientRegister>(async register =>
    {
        await register.ExecuteAsync(builder.Services);
    });
```

Comment: True. That worked for me (and so did "otherClient.GetBaseAdress().Result"). The only problem that bothers me is that GetAwaiter().GetResult() blocks synchronously and has the potential for deadlocks (at least that was the case prior .net 7.0)

Comment: @IvanStudenikin Can you use [IWebHost and its StartAsync](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-2/)?

Comment: Not sure if that helps. Any examples out there?

Comment: @IvanStudenikin I've updated my post, could you please check it again?